# Prove no solution exists for $a^3=b^5$ and $c^3=d^5$ if $c-a=32$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given the following problem:

Given the positive integers $a, b, c,$ and $d,$ such that $a^3=b^5$ and $c^3=d^5$. 
If also, $c-a=32$, prove there is no solution with $a, b, c,$ and $d,$ as integers.

I have been given the hint that we need to use a "big theorem that you should know very well"

Can anyone give me direction to that particular theorem?
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't solved the problem, but the big theorem which jumps immediately to mind is Fermat's Last.

Comment: Peter- I thought of that too, but haven't gotten very far with it since my powers aren't equal. I will look deeper into that. Thanks

Comment: Mabe it is helpful to notice that $32=2^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $a$ is a perfect fifth power, as is $c$. But a difference of fifth powers cannot be a fifth power $32$.

Of course we do not need the full Fermat Last Theorem for this, The special case of fifth powers was settled long ago, by Dirichlet. And one can give a very elementary proof that there do not exist non-zero integers $x$, $y$ such that $x^5+32=y^5$.

Comment: I think that the answer by Wojohn is better, and should be the one accepted. The big theorem is the unique factorization theorem, since as pointed out in my answer, though there is a connection with FLT, we do not really need it. (I would have upvoted Wojohn's answer, but I have run out of upvotes for today.)

Answer (score 5):

Let's denote $n=a^3=b^5,m=c^3=d^5$. Our big theorem will be uniqueness of prime factorization: because $n$ is a cube, every exponent in prime factorization must be divisible by $3$. At the same time, every exponent is divisible by $5$. So every exponent is divisble by $15$, and $n=k^{15}$ for some $k$. We then have $a=\sqrt[3]{n}=\sqrt[3]{k^{15}}=k^5$, so $a$ is a $5$-th power. In exactly the same way, $c$ is a $5$-th power. Now we must notice that difference of two positive $5$-th power is equal to $32$, which is easy now, even without using even bigger theorem which is Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: Thanks! We have been talking about prime factorization, but I was trying to apply it to simply say $a^3$ and $b^5$ both had the same prime factorization. I didn't think to use the divisibility of the exponents!